# How to host a Silverlight app in a Sharepoint 2007 Web Part

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint

There has been a flurry of updates released to Microsoft's Silverlight over the past couple of months (Silverlight 2 beta 2 runtime + dev tools, RC0 + dev tools which broke beta 2 apps), and recently Microsoft has released the RTM.

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to integrate Sharepoint 2007 and Silverlight. Many of the sharepoint/silverlight blogs i have read are outdated, meaning that they target SL Beta 2.

So, my question is...

**What steps are necessary in order to host a Silverlight 2.0 (RTM) application, in a web part, on Sharepoint Server 2007 ?**

Comment: +1, interesting blend of technologies. A better question might be "Has this ever been done?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this out but
it seems like a good start:

[Silverlight Blueprint for SharePoint](http://www.codeplex.com/SL4SP)

Comment: i agree that its a good start, but the samples have not been updated to the RTM. Looks like they are working on that =D

Answer (score 2):

This isn't too difficult to do. There are a few steps you need to follow:

1. [Update IIS with the xap mime type](http://blogs.conchango.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2008/03/10/configure-mime-type-for-silverlight-2-0-in-iis.aspx).
2. Put your files some that SharePoint can get them. In our case we developed a feature which deployed the silverlight javascript files and our xap out to folders in the ISAPI folder (%Program Files%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\ISAPI). We created a folder called _xaps to host these files.
3. Put the Silverlight object code in either the page itself or in a content web part.

[EDIT: For some reason my object code isn't showing up. So [here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx) to an example instead]

That's all there is to it. You're probably best off creating a feature to copy of the files and update whatever page you're hosting the control in. But to just stick silverlight in SharePoint the above should work.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Karine/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=40

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using User Controls [i.e. Web Parts], then I'd highly recommend looking at SmartPart. You'll still need to do the things in the blogs above to get the assemblies recognized, trusted, etc, but this may help you get your user controls deployed faster.